# Ovelap 3 histograms each one with its own Normal distrubutions, on the same plot?

Tags: r, csv, histogram, normal-distribution

How do I overlap 3 histograms each one with its own normal distributions, on the same plot? To have a graph like this one? The image shows the last points when a molecule moves 100, 1000, and 10000 times:

[image]

I already have the histograms with its own normal distributions by themselves on R. I used this code for that...

```
 # histograms
 b=read.csv("pruebab.csv")
 b=b$pruebab
 hist(b, freq = F,
      ylab = "Densidad",
      xlab = "Alturas (cm)", main = "")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(b), sd(b)),
       col = "blue", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
 hist(b, freq = F,
      ylab = "casualities",
      xlab = "meters", main = "")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(b), sd(b)),
       col = "blue", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

An example of my histogram with its distribution function:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse) 
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, 0, 1), y = rnorm(1000, 0, 3), z = rnorm(1000, 0, 5))
df <- melt(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = ..count.., group = variable, fill = variable)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = .6, binwidth = .5) +
  geom_density(alpha = .1, size = 1.2, aes(color = variable)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heres is how you do it:

```
h2 = rnorm(1000,4)
h1 = rnorm(1000,6)

# Histogram Grey Color
hist(h1, col=rgb(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5),xlim=c(0,9), ylim=c(0,0.4), main="Overlapping Histogram", prob=T)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(h1), sd=sd(h1)),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,200), add=TRUE,
      col = "blue", lwd = 3)

hist(h2, col=rgb(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.5), add=T,prob = T)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(h2)),
      col = "red", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

you are missing the `add = TRUE` in the second and third histogram